# How to get specific records with remaining records?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Let's say I've got some records like, And I want to get all cars where **type="honda" and doors="4"** with all remaining records also

```
<Car id="1", type="honda", doors="4" created_at: "2015.01.01">
<Car id="2", type="jeep",  created_at: "2015.01.01">
<Car id="3", type="mazda", created_at: "2015.01.01">
<Car id="4", type="honda", doors="4" created_at: "2015.01.01">
<Car id="5", type="honda", doors="2" created_at: "2015.01.01">
<Car id="6", type="honda", doors="2" created_at: "2015.01.01">
```

I want to get this:

```
<Car id="1", type="honda", doors="4" created_at: "2015.01.01">
<Car id="2", type="jeep",  created_at: "2015.01.01">
<Car id="3", type="mazda", created_at: "2015.01.01">
<Car id="4", type="honda", doors="4" created_at: "2015.01.01">
```

I have this query but it's returning only cars where **type="honda" and doors="4"** Mainly i don't want to list other types with `IS NOT` as I'm not sure about their values.

```
Car.where("type = ? AND doors = ?", "honda", "4")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR` operator to select other types than **"honda"**

```
Car.where("(type = ? AND doors = ?) OR type <> ?", "honda", "4", "honda")
```

Comment: <> is the "not equal" operator.

You can upvote and mark this answer as solution if it is